# mathjs DimensionError thown on load

Tags: node.js, mathjs

Trying to use the mathjs module for some matrix maths in NodeJS. The require statement seems to throw an exception

```js
var math = require("mathjs");
```

Exception is:

```
  DimensionError
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jon_000\workspace\RobotInvKin\node_modules
\mathjs\lib\error\DimensionError.js:30:28)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jon_000\workspace\RobotInvKin\node_modules
\mathjs\lib\utils\array.js:8:22)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jon_000\workspace\RobotInvKin\node_modules
\mathjs\lib\utils\index.js:3:17)
```

This must be something simple. Any ideas gratefully received?

Comment: What version of node.js are you using, and what version of math.js?

Comment: Node 0.12.7. mathjs 2.3.0

Comment: I have started a windows 8 machine, installed node 0.12.7, installed math.js v2.3.0, and loaded math.js into node, it all works fine. Did you try to re-install math.js? Could it be like your local installation of math.js or node is somehow corrupted?